# Find the smallest $N$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{p_k}>\pi$. (The $p_k$'s are the prime numbers.)

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, prime-numbers

How to solve the following problem?

> Let $\{p_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be the set of primes (in increasing order). What is the smallest integer $N$ such that
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{p_k}>\pi?$$

We know that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{p_k}$ diverges, so $N$ must exists. Moreover, the sum diverges like $\log\log N$ (very, very slowly) so we could get an $N$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{p_k}$ will be pretty close to $\pi$.

I tried to solve this problem numerically, but it takes such a long time to compute that I wasn't able to get the result. Is there a clever way to find it?

Comment: I cannot check this, but I hope you're being honest and not asking us to solve some Project Euler problem for you! It wouldn't be fair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{3\ 260\ 805}\frac{1}{p_k} &= 3.1415926\color{blue}{396}... \\
\pi &= 3.1415926\color{blue}{535}... \\
\sum_{k=1}^{3\ 260\ 806}\frac{1}{p_k} &= 3.1415926\color{blue}{579}...
\end{align}
$$
so
$$N=3\ 260\ 806.$$

Comment: A little question, how did you calculate those sums? If I try to make a list of primes in Python, it freezes when I ask for too many.

Comment: @Farnight Wolfram Mathematica 10.0

Comment: It has often been discussed on MSE that Mathematica-based answers without any theoretical justification count only as "half-answers".

Comment: At least, what was the Mathematica code that produced the result?

Comment: @AlexM. I just used trial and errors by varying k in Sum[N[1/Prime[n], 12], {n, 1, k}]

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes), one has $\sum \limits _{p \leq N} \frac 1 p \geq \log \log (N+1) - \log \frac {\pi^2} 6$. Now, this sum can be rewritten as $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^{\pi(N)} \frac 1 {p_n}$ and since $\pi(N) \leq N$ we have that $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^{N} \frac 1 {p_n} \geq \log \log (\pi(N) + 1) - \log \frac {\pi^2} 6$. In turn, [we know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) that $\pi(N) \geq \frac N {\log N}$, so you get $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^{N} \frac 1 {p_n} \geq \log \log ( \frac N {\log N} +1) - \log \frac {\pi^2} 6$.

The only thing to do now is to impose some inequalities: if we call $C= \pi + \log \frac {\pi^2} 6$ and take into account that $\frac N {\log N} \geq \frac N {\sqrt N}$, we have to look for $N$ such that $\log \log \sqrt N \geq C$, which gives $N \geq \mathbb{e}^{2 \mathbb{e}^C}$. Now, starting from this value (at which the inequality is *guaranteed* to hold) go backwards bisecting your intervals until you find the minimum such $N$. Since bisecting takes $O(\log N)$ steps, this will be *really* fast even for an old computer.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem.

Comment: @Farnight: Why? One has now to impose $\log \log \frac N {\log N} \geq \pi + \log \frac {\pi^2} 6$. Does this seem too difficult, or are you seeing some other problem?

Comment: It doesn't help us if we want to find the smallest $N$ satisfying the condition.

Comment: It does inasmuch it offers an upper bound for $N$. Then one may go backwards starting from this upper bound, looking for the smallest $N$.

Comment: Just to put this in perspective: With $N=3260806$, we have $\log\log(\frac N{\log N}+1)-\log{\frac{\pi^2}6}\approx 2.01$, which is way off. To get anywhere near $\pi$, you'd need $N\approx 10^{18}$ and surely don't want to work backwards from there

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Of course you can work backwards from there, by bisecting your intervals. This only needs $O(\log N)$ steps, which is *really* fast. Working backwards does not have to mean "decreasing by 1" at every step.

Comment: @AlexM. But you still need to calculate the sum at every step, which should take a lot of time.

Comment: @Farnight: Agreed, that's why I've asked Spenser to show us his Mathematica code that solved the problem, to see what he used to get the result so fast.